# FirstOrDefaultAsync returning System.NullReferenceException [error origin not clear]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nullreferenceexception

I am working on building an ASP.NET Core Web API and am continuously getting `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` 
My model was working fine and it suddenly started throwing an error. Here is my DB entity class:

```
public class LocationEntity
{
    protected LocationEntity() { }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string NormalizeTitle { get => this.Title.ToUpper(); set => value = this.Title.ToUpper(); }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get => _dateCreated; set => _dateCreated = value; }

    DateTime _dateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Then I have an area entity inherited from location:

```
public class AreaEntity : LocationEntity
{
    public AreaEntity() { }

    [Required]
    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
    public CountryEntity Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid StateId { get; set; }
    public StateEntity State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CityId { get; set; }
    public CityEntity City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SubCityId { get; set; }
    public SubCityEntity SubCity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Pincode { get; set; }

}
```

In my AddressService.cs, I have a function named PopulateMasterData:

```
AreaEntity area = null;
var country = await _context.tbl_Country.Where(x => x.NormalizeTitle == model.Country.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

          if (country.IsNull())
              country = (await _context.tbl_Country.AddAsync(new CountryEntity { Title = model.Country })).Entity;
```

and similarly checking for state, city etc as well and creating the area entity if fields are unique.

I am getting the error at this step in the LocationEntity class

```
[Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string NormalizeTitle { get => this.Title.ToUpper(); set => value = this.Title.ToUpper();
```

I do not understand the reason for this error and what is not beung initialised for this to happen.
Could someone explain?

EDIT: CountryEntity:

```
 public class CountryEntity: LocationEntity
{
    public CountryEntity() { }
}
```

Comment: Is `this.Title` perhaps `null` ? And your setter is wrong, you shouldn't set `value`, you should *read* `value`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen since it was working fine earlier, I don't understand why it's returning a null exception when in fact the country exists in DB. And if it does not, i am initialising the country entity and then adding a new one. I am new to this and I don't understand why it stopped working suddenly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class. When you are instantiating the class and setting the value for `NormalizeTitle` property, the object is not yet created. That's why you're getting a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: It is first checking in the country DB if the country in post request exists or not, and if it does not, it is initialising a new CountryEntity var and adding it to DB. I am not getting why it's throwing error at FirstOrDefaultAsync

Comment: Your code shows that `CountryEntity` inherits from `LocationEntity` and that means that when you are initialising a new `CountryEntity` var you're creating an object which is instantiating both `CountryEntity` and `LocationEntity` classes. Therefore, due to a new instance of `LocationEntity` is being created, you cannot set its `NormalizeTitle` property value by refering itself with the `this` keyword as it doesn't exists at this time.

Comment: Thank you the explanation, it helped! I added `string _title = string.Empty`; in `LocantionEntity` and `public string Title { get => _title; set => _title = value; }` and it is letting my call ToUpper() and not giving the Null Exception error anymore.

Comment: You're very welcome! Happy coding :)